# When my power apps app open its showing some office365 error message

Tags: sharepoint, office365, power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am getting error `Office365Users.ManagerV2 failed: {"error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "User not found", "InnerError": { "date": "2023-11-08T13:15:01", "requesr-id": " ", "client-request-id": " "} } }`

But in edit mode its not giving any warning or error

I am trying to get current login user's manger and manager's of manager. Bellow I am using PowerApps formula is `Office365Users.ManagerV2(TextInput2.Text).mail` on `default` property of textbox field

First field is `Office365Users.ManagerV2(User().Email).mail`

I don't know where I am wrong in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you will get errors and usually it is about timing, luckily these resolve themselves. So use `IfError`.

First one:

```
IfError( Office365Users.ManagerV2(User().Email).mail, "" )
```

Second one:

```
If( !IsBlank(TextInput2.Text),
  IfError( Office365Users.ManagerV2(TextInput2.Text).mail, "" )
)
```